# Why doesn't my selection sort with XOR swap work?

Tags: java, sorting

I can't tell what's wrong because all of it seems to be more or less straight from the book. I attached the JUnit tests as well

```
public final class SelectionSort {
    
    /**
     * Implementation of selection sort algorithm.
     * 
     * @param x The integer array to sort in place
     */
    public static int[] array;
    public static void sort(int[] x) {
        array = x;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; ++i) {
            // Assume i is index of smallest value in array
            int min = i;
            
            // Check all other values in array to find smallest value
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; ++j) {
                if (array[j] < array[min]) {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            
            // Swap smallest value to its correct location
            swap(array, i, min);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Swap two values in place using XOR algorithm.
     * 
     * @param x The array of values
     * @param a Index of first value in x
     * @param b Index of second value in x
     */
    private static void swap(int[] x, int ii, int minn) {
        array[ii] ^= array[minn];
        array[minn] ^= array[ii];
        array[ii] ^= array[minn];
    }
}
```

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class SelectionSortTest {

    @Test
    void testAlreadySorted() {
        int[] x = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
        SelectionSort.sort(x);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[] {1, 2, 3}, x);
    }
    
    @Test
    void testHighLow() {
        int[] x = new int[] {3, 2, 1};
        SelectionSort.sort(x);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[] { 1, 2, 3}, x);
    }
    
    @Test
    void testRandom() {
        int[] x = new int[] {2, 1, 3};
        SelectionSort.sort(x);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[] {1, 2, 3}, x);
    }
    
    @Test
    void testHighLow321() {
        int[] x = new int[] {3, 2, 1};
        SelectionSort.sort(x);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[] {3, 2, 1}, x);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Including the actual failure in the question itself would make this easier to answer (so folks don't need to comb through or run it themselves to know what to look for).

Comment: Why/how `testHighLow321` is supposed to expect an array sorted in descending order?

Comment: Exactly as Alex said: you have two tests that are contradicting each other:
'testHighLow' and 'testHighLow321'.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two mistakes in your code:
Firstly, as Alex Rudenko and Stijn Dejongh said, there is one test case that can't work, because it's in the wrong order. Secondly, if minn is equal to ii, e.g. in the first test-case, the swap fails and sets the value equal to zero. A better approach would be:

```
private static void swap(final int[] arr, final int firstIdx, final int secondIdx) {
    if(firstIdx == secondIdx)
        return;

    arr[firstIdx] ^= arr[secondIdx];
    arr[secondIdx] ^= arr[firstIdx];
    arr[firstIdx] ^= arr[secondIdx];
}
```